# Node webservice in Docker with entrypoint fails but works otherwise

Tags: node.js, docker

I am running a node web service inside docker container.

When I run Docker container with entrypoint

```
CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

it gives me the below mentioned error.

When I use

```
CMD /bin/bash
```

and enter the contianer and run node app.js then my application works fine

This is the error:

```
Error: Module did not self-register.
at Error (native)
at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:435:18)
at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at bindings (/usr/src/app/controlcenter/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/controlcenter/node_modules/couchbase/lib/binding.js:143:36)
at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/controlcenter/node_modules/couchbase/lib/couchbase.js:3:15)
at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
```

node version v0.10.37

npm -version 1.4.28

nvm --version 0.33.0

My entire Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/controlcenter
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/controlcenter

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils \
build-essential \
apt-transport-https \
build-essential  \
wget \
curl \
vim \
python

RUN \
  apt-get -y install software-properties-common && \
  add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa  && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jdk && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/

RUN wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v4.2.6/node-v4.2.6.tar.gz -P /tmp/ && \
  tar xvzf /tmp/node-v4.2.6.tar.gz && cd node-v* && \
  ./configure && \
  make && \
  make test && \
  make install

COPY . /usr/src/app/controlcenter/

ENV NVM_DIR "$HOME/.nvm"
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-7-jdk

RUN npm install sails -g \
&& npm install grunt-cli -g \
&& npm install jsonlint-lines -g \
&& npm install node-ninja -g

RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.0/install.sh | bash \
&& /bin/sh "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" \
&& . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" \
&& nvm install 0.10.37 \
&& nvm use 0.10.37 \
&& npm install jdbc \
&& rm -rf node_modules/couchbase/ \
&& npm install couchbase\
&& nvm alias default 0.10.37


EXPOSE 1337

CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

Comment: tried `CMD ["/bin/bash ","node", "app.js"]` ?

Comment: unfortunately this does not work

Comment: please post your entire Dockerfile if possible.

Comment: @WebertS.Lima added

Comment: Will you mention the full command you use to run your conatiner ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are copying the whole application directory into the docker image, with the node_modules directory. This `npm install` was executed with your local node version (v0.10.37) and you are installing another one in your container (v4.2.6) so maybe this is the problem.

I recommend you to remove your node_modules directory and execute the `npm install` command in your Dockerfile.

So:

- Go to your application directory in your host and execute:

  > rm -rf node_modules
- Add a layer in your Dockerfile to do the `npm install` command after the copy one.

  > ...
  >
  > COPY . /usr/src/app/controlcenter/
  >
  > RUN npm install
  >
  > ...
- Run the container again.

Comment: This fixed my issue. It was the problem in versions of npm and the solution you recommend actually fixes it. Thanks